# Misunderstood in Verilog basics?

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, simulation

I'm quite new to Verilog.  I have some code working, but from time to
time, I get some incomprehensible behavior, and I think I lack some knowledge in Verilog.

Here is a quick example of a more complex project. It works with the `div2`
module (`/* go */`), and it doesn't with the `div5` module (`/* no go */`). Go / no go
means I got `ssoc` signal on LED2 debug output or not.

```
module test_div_1(

       /* iCEstick clk (12MHz) */

       input  clkin,

       /* 10MHz ref_in */

       input  ref_in,

       /* iCEstick leds */

       output LED_GREEN, 

       output LED0, output LED1, output LED2, output LED3,

          /* ADC (DIV) spi */

       );   

   

   SB_PLL40_CORE #(

       .FEEDBACK_PATH("SIMPLE"),

       /* $ icepll -i 12 -o 30 */

       /* clkin=12MHz */

       .DIVR(0),    /* DIVR =  0  (div 1) */

       .DIVF(79),      /* DIVF = 79 (x80) */

       .DIVQ(5),    /* DIVQ =  5 (div 6) */

       /* main_clk=30MHz */

       .FILTER_RANGE(3'b001)  /* FILTER_RANGE = 1 */

       ) uut (

        .LOCK(LED_GREEN),

        .RESETB(1'b1),

        .BYPASS(1'b0),

        .REFERENCECLK(clkin),

        .PLLOUTCORE(main_clk)

        );

   

   

   wire      main_clk;

   wire      ref_in;

   wire            soc;         

   reg        ssoc;

   wire       spi_m_clk;

   

   /* soc generator (125kHz) */

   div80 d80_1(ref_in, soc);

      

   /* cs and clk generation */

/* -----\/----- EXCLUDED -----\/-----

   div2 div_spi_clk(ref_in, spi_m_clk); /-* go *-/

 -----/\----- EXCLUDED -----/\----- */

   div5 div_spi_clk(ref_in, spi_m_clk); /* no go */

   always @ (negedge spi_m_clk)

     ssoc<=soc;

   

   

   /* TODO: remove (debug) */

   assign LED0=spi_m_clk;

   assign LED1=soc;

   assign LED2=ssoc;

   assign LED3=1'b0;   

endmodule /* # test_div_1 end # */

module div80(input in,

        output out);

   wire        in;

   reg          out;

   reg [6:0]        c;

   initial

     begin

  c=7'b0000000;

     end

   

   always@(posedge in)

     begin

  if(c>=79)

    begin

       c<=0;

       out<=1'b1;

    end

  else

    begin

       out<=1'b0;

       c<=c+1;

    end

     end

   

endmodule /* # div80 end # */

module div5(input in,

        output out);

   wire        in;

   reg         out;

   reg [2:0]        c;

   

   initial

     begin

  c=3'b000;
     end

   

   always@(posedge in)
     begin
  if(c>=4)

    begin
       c<=0;
       out<=1'b1;
    end

  else
    begin
       out<=1'b0;
       c<=c+1;
    end
     end
endmodule /* # div5 end # */

module div2(input in,
      output out);

   wire            in, out;
   reg             c;

   always@(posedge in)
     begin
  c<=!c;
     end
   assign out=c;

endmodule /* # div2 end # */
```

The `div80` module output works fine.

Is my mistake related to something about `wire`/`reg`, or anything else?

I'm using ice40stick and icestorm toolchain (yosys, nextpnr and icepack).

Could you help me understand why my design does not behave properly?

Answer (score 2):

When I try to compile your code with a couple simulators, I get multiple warning for your `div5` and `div2` modules.  If you do not get warning messages with your simulator, try your code on the simulators on EDAPlayground.

Here is the code without any warnings:

```
module div5(input in,
            output reg out);
   reg [2:0]       c;

   initial
     begin
        c=3'b000;
     end

   always@(posedge in)
     begin
        if(c>=4)
          begin
             c<=0;
             out<=1'b1;
          end
        else
          begin
             out<=1'b0;
             c<=c+1;
          end
     end
endmodule /* # div5 end # */

module div2(input in,
            output out);
   reg             c;

   always@(posedge in)
     begin
        c<=!c;
     end
   assign out=c;
endmodule /* # div2 end # */
```

In `div5`, you make assignments to `out` from procedural code (`always` block).  This means you need to declare `out` as `reg`.  In `div2`, you use a procedural `assign` statement, which means you should not declare it as a `reg`.